# Reading csv files and importing data into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv

I'm successfully reading numbers from a `.csv` file into SQL Server with below statement, assuming that I've created a linked server named CSV_IMPORT.

```
select * 
from CSV_IMPORT...Sophos#csv
```

However, the problem is that if I have a comma with numbers as data, it will show NULL instead of a correct one. How can I read the "54,375" correctly into SQL Server? Thank you very much for your help.

Below is the data in csv file.

```
09/07/2017,52029,70813,10898,6691,6849,122,25,147427
09/08/2017,47165,61253,6840,5949,5517,75,2,126801
09/14/2017,"54,375","16944","15616","2592","3280",380,25,"96390"
```

This is the result from the statement:

```
2017-09-07 00:00:00.000 52029   70813   10898   6691    6849    122 25  147427
2017-09-08 00:00:00.000 47165   61253   6840    5949    5517    75  2   126801
2017-09-14 00:00:00.000 NULL    16944   15616   2592    3280    380 25  96390
```

Comment: That depends very heavily on how your linked server is set up. What driver does it use? Please post the creation DDL for it. If it uses Jet or Excel or anything like that, it's very dumb about this kind of stuff. You may wish to use `BULK INSERT` instead to insert as a text file rather than using the annoying Jet driver

Comment: Well, even if you cannot solve it during the import phase: you could import everything into an intermediate table with `varchar` columns first, do a `replace(col,',','.')` on these columns and then insert the whole thing into your final table.

Comment: The linked server provider is MS Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider, and I setup the linked server provider string as Text.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go would be using temporary table. Read all data as text, then replace every comma in whole table to dot (`.`), if you want it as decimal separator, or to empty string(`''`) if it's a thousand separator, then load data to exisitng table converting everything (you don't have to do it explicitly, SQL does it implictly).

Comment: What if the comma is a thousand separator?

Comment: In the question is specified that is decimal separator. And how would you go around number which has comma as thousand and decimal separator? I.e. how would you interpret 1,234,567? Should it be 1234,567 or maybe 1234567?

Comment: Where in the question does it specify that it is the decimal separator? All the other numbers in the csv are integers, so the logical assumption is that 54,375 is as well.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Edited my question accordingly. Thank you :)

Comment: Since we changed the way feeding data into this csv, somehow there are double quotes added to numbers if it's greater than 9999. The given example was just made up by me. In fact, all numbers greater than 9999 now are having a comma inside and double quotes surrounding them.

Comment: Tried below codes to read to a temp but it still fails. Since just a simple select statement wouldn't read data well, I'm not sure if a TempTable will work here. Or am I missing something here?

`create table #TempTable
(
DateValue varchar(50),
Legitimate varchar(50),
BlockedConnections varchar(50),
BulkMessages varchar(50),
SpamMedium varchar(50),
SpamHigh varchar(50),
Other varchar(50),
Viruses varchar(50),
Total varchar(50)
)

go
USE CFCDB;
GO
INSERT into #TempTable SELECT * from CSV_IMPORT...Sophos#csv;
GO`

Comment: Try it, see if it works. If so, then carry on wih your transformation.

Comment: No, it is not working. It reads the data to the temp table successfully, but the field is still showing NULL.

Comment: That's because you CAN'T use comma anywhere if it's separator (thousend or decimal). You need to change the value separator then. You have to tell poeple that create CSV files to change their logic, because this is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I did a project for a client which involved importing csv files, which were meant to be the same format, but which came from different sources and hence were inconsistent (even to the point of using different separators according to source).  I ended up writing a CLR routine, which read the csv line by line, parsed the content, and added it to a DataTable.  This DataTable I then inserted to SQL Server using the SqlBulkCopy class.

The advantage of this approach, was that I was totally in control of dealing with all anomalies in the file.  It was also much faster than the alternative of inserting the whole file into a temporary table of varchars and then parsing within SQL Server.  Effectively I did one line by line parse in c# and one bulk insert of parsed data.

Comment: After rethinking the problem, this is best way to do (and only IMO). But OP didn't mention using any external software / programming language.